# Error Creating table in SQL table already exists

Tags: android, sql, create-table

I have written commands to create table in `onCreate()` method of `DatabaseManager` class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. When opening database, the `onCreate()` method is being called for the first time. but still there is an error saying table corporate_boxes already exists.

The open method

```
public DatabaseManager open() {  

   ourHelper = new DatabaseManager(context);  
   ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
   return this;  

}
```

Oncreate Method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE2);
}
```

`DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE2` is a string whos definition is given below,

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE2 = "CREATE TABLE "
+ DATABASE_TABLE2 + " ( " + KEY_ROWID
+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_PRODUCT
+ " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_IMAGEID
+ " TEXT NOT NULL );";
```

I also tried with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` but still it is giving the same error.

Here is the stacktrace that is being displayed.

```
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table corporate_boxes already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE corporate_boxes ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, _name TEXT NOT NULL, _price TEXT NOT NULL,_imageid TEXT NOT NULL );
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at appistic.services.tricouschocolates.categories.DatabaseManager.onCreate(DatabaseManager.java:199)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at appistic.services.tricouschocolates.categories.DatabaseManager.open(DatabaseManager.java:116)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at appistic.services.tricouschocolates.Products.onItemSelected(Products.java:51)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-21 07:59:38.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Just a wild guess since the error does not make sense when you use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS: try to remove the trailing `;` from your create statement.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is **`;`** character because other code looks correct. This character can cause mysterious problems so try to remove its from DML statement and it should works.

I can't understand why this error is thrown also when you use `if not exists` in query, because `onCreate()` i called only first time you use some 'action' with db and then db is always only opened for reading or writing or both.

Comment: it is still giving the same error but i have used an if around the table with the condition that (!db.isOpen()) and it is doing the work for me. By the way do you know where exactly the SQL file get stored ?

Comment: so in application path in databases directory(internal directories of application). or you can copy db and save it on sd card and just read from there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data base version number and try once it may use full to you.